# Is there a way to categorize code so that I can minimize something and use a comment to write what it does for organization?

Tags: java

This is a bit unorthodox and also I am relatively new to coding but here is what I want to do:

I am trying to make a flashcard simulator (like quizlet) to practice coding, and I have so far successfully made a program that takes a text file with terms and definitions and converts it into two arrays (terms and definitions).
Now this is taking up a lot of space for me looking at it, and I notice you can minimize certain loops and things so it just shows the top line, to reduce clutter. So I want to minimize the whole function for looking at and just write a comment next to it saying what it does, so its like a line of code.

The problem is any redundant loops (like a for loop that executes once) make the arrays unusable outside of that loop. So any ideas if I want to do this?

My best idea is a method but since I am a beginner I don't entirely know how to do that yet and my impression is that it would be outside of the main method and separate from the code which is not what I want cause I only use it once.

Thanks,

This is my code if you want it:

```java
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Flashcards.txt"));

        String[] terms = new String[128];
        String[] defs = new String[128];

        String term;
        String def;
        String line;
        byte c = 0;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            boolean after = false;
            def = "";
            term = "";
            for (short i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                if (line.charAt(i) == ':')
                    after = true;
                else if (!after)
                    term = term + line.charAt(i);
                else
                    def = def + line.charAt(i);
            }
            terms[c] = term;
            defs[c]= def.strip();
            c++;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my personal opinion, a method isn't a bad idea, even if you are only going to use it once. A method would allow you to move all your code outside your main method and reduce it to one line of code, collapse it outside of the main method, and make your code more maintainable in the future. Editors like Eclipse (I don't know about Netbeans or InteliJ) do not allow you to collapse your code in the way that you want.

Comment: It still doesn't let me use the arrays that I wrote to within the method, since it only seems to exist within that method.

Comment: Consider passing the arrays as arguments. Then you should be able to access them in the main method

Answer (score 0):

Saw this looking through my stack overflow profile's history (now intermediate programmer not absolute beginner) and thought I would answer:

yes you should probably just use a function outside of your main function, even if you only invoke it once. You can pass in any parameters you want the function to see. You can pass in parameters you want it to modify and modify those parameters in the function, IF the parameters are references to objects and not primitives (lists do meet the criteria for this in Java I am pretty sure). However I think its better practice generally to not modify anything you get passed in and instead return a copy of the parameter that is modified, and set the original variable to = that when you call the function. If you want to return multiple variables there are ways to do that depending on the language.
I think doing this is pretty standard.

Another concept I've heard of though for you to look into is called an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression).
Another thing you can do is wrap code with {} as long as you don't use any variables you declare in that scope outside of that scope. I mention this below.

a guy on youtube I saw doesn't think you should extract into methods, he talks about what he would do instead at in [this video](https://youtu.be/QM1iUe6IofM?t=2235) at the timestamp linked.
He mentions how you can put { } around code in many languages including java, which answers my question I think. He also proposes a non-existing syntax use(var name) {}. It goes to show beginner me wasn't the only one thinking about this kind of stuff.
But yeah at this moment both ways seem fine to me.

Also if you indent something you can collapse it in VSCode but I'm not sure anybody does this or would think it looks good.